# How to prevent pgfplots from using the 10^n notation for axis ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When creating a plot like this one

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis} 
                \addplot coordinates {
                (0.01,0.01)
                (0.09,0.09)
                };
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

pgfplot uses the following `xticklabels`:

[image: produced output]

Is there any way to make pgfplots create labels as `0.01,0.02,...` without specifying them all manually using `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Section **4.12 Number formatting options** from `pgfplots` manual sends you to `pgfplotstable` manual where in section **2.7 Number formatting options** you can find the solution.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false, tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed} ]
                \addplot coordinates {
                (0.01,0.01)
                (0.09,0.09)
                };
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]