# How can I remove 10^(−n) notation for values less than 1 in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks, axis

I have the following semi-logarithmic plot (y-axis() that has the ticks with 10 raised to non-integer powers as shown in figure.

[image]

I have referred to both these answers [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier),[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/how-to-prevent-pgfplots-from-using-the-10n-notation-for-axis-ticks). However, both failed to get the real decimal notation in this case (0.16, 0.20, 0.25) instead show (10^−0.8, 10^−0.7, 10^−0.6). The answers in  [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier),[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/how-to-prevent-pgfplots-from-using-the-10n-notation-for-axis-ticks) work for other values as shown in the second plot in MWE.

How can I remove 10^(−n) notation for values less than 1?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
      scaled y ticks = false,
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
      /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace % Optional if you want to replace comma as the 1000 separator 
      }]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (100,0.200001)
  (200,0.200003)
  (300,0.200005)
  };    
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
      scaled y ticks = false,
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
      /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace % Optional if you want to replace comma as the 1000 separator 
      }]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (100,0.0200001)
  (200,10.200003)
  (300,110.200005)
  };    
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
      scaled y ticks = false,
      log ticks with fixed point,  % <---- added (replace your "y tick label style"
                   ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (100,0.200001)
  (200,0.200003)
  (300,0.200005)
  };
\end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
      scaled y ticks = false,
      log ticks with fixed point,  % <---- added (replace your "y tick label style"
                    ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (100,0.0200001)
  (200,10.200003)
  (300,110.200005)
  };
\end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```