# Remove tick scale label without changing values

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

I am trying to remove the tick scale label (10^n) without changing the values on the axis. The idea being that I want to give the base as the unit of the graph, not as a scale label.

I have the following MWE, stolen from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/how-to-prevent-pgfplots-from-using-the-10n-notation-for-axis-ticks) where the person asking wanted the values to adapt the scale label, I want to remove the scale label, but keep the values as if it was there.

My idea is that SI units are usually nice when doing calculations, but they might not be nice when showing the data, so I have some large data set (here represented by two points) with points given in the unit meter, but i want to write the unit on the x axis as centimeters.

If I add the option `scaled x ticks=false` I get the values 0.01 and 0.09 on the axis. I want to have the values 1 and 9 appear, but without the scale label.

I am aware that I can do this by manually setting `xticklabels`, but what if I later figure out that I would rather give the unit in nano meters?

The best way to do this is to set the parameter `scaled x ticks=base 10:9` and then change the `xlabel={l [\si{\nano\meter}]}` without the scale label changing.

I'm trying to find something in the pgfplots documentation, but this might just be a case of not knowing what key to look for

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis} 
                \addplot coordinates {
                (0.01,0.01)
                (0.09,0.09)
                };
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: produced output]

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %<-consider using this
\pgfplotsset{hide scale/.style={
/pgfplots/xtick scale label code/.code={},
/pgfplots/ytick scale label code/.code={}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[hide scale] 
                \addplot coordinates {
                (0.01,0.01)
                (0.09,0.09)
                };
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This worked perfectly ;-)